# Sqlite3 Case statement weirdness

Tags: sqlite

I have the following case statement on a TEXT file and I'm trying to get it to say '' instead of none.

```
CASE CustomField1
                When 'None' 
                    then ''
                Else CAST(CustomField1 as INT)
            End ReceiptLoc
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with this.  If the column is NULL then put nothing in the column or empty string is fine.  I've tried replacing 'None' with NULL and NaN.  What am I missing?

I'm more of a SQL Server person so This is a little different for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use searched `CASE` expression:

```
CASE WHEN CustomField1 IS NULL THEN ''
     WHEN CustomField1 = 'None' THEN ''
     Else CAST(CustomField1 AS INT)
End ReceiptLoc
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16&fiddle=12b9c009bfed9f393d0136bc29e551ce)**

Comment: Thank you very much